# crm 2011 Subgrid record selected/OnFocus Event

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I have a subgrid on my contact entity.

[image: This is image]

I want that when the first record is selected in the subgrid above buttons enables and
disables on uncheck.

I know how to enable diable button but i dont know where/how to call my function.

Comment: Are you building a custom ribbon?

Comment: No these are not ribbon buttons... these are javascript button in html

Comment: So you are building a custom ribbon then? Why not use the more straight forward method of a ribbon button?

Comment: As far as I know there is no supported way to add an onChange/OnFocus to a grid. Related info; http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/crm-2013-adding-an-on-change-event-to-a-sub-grid/

Comment: Posted this awhile ago. It might be of helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656748/subgrid-restrict-user-to-select-only-one-record/20671278#20671278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code on the OnLoad Form event, to access the subgrid onClick Event.

```
function OnLoad() {
    var subGridId = gridId + "_d";

    var grid = document.getElementById(subGridId);

    if( grid != null){
        grid.onclick = ClickAction;
    }

}

function ClickAction() {
    //insert your Click action here.
}
```